# Windows Phone IsolatedStorageSettings & Mutex

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, mutex, windows-phone

I'm developing an app for Windows Phone. This app uses background agent (scheduled task).

The main app stores some settings with help of [IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.applicationsettings%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). And background agent sometimes can only read values from settings.

The question is should I use [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.threading.mutex%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to synchronize operations on [IsolatedStorageSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) between the main app and the background agent? Or this is not needed in my scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  [More...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202944%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

> For Periodic and Resource-intensive Agents: Use LINQ 2 SQL or a file
>   in isolated storage that is guarded with a Mutex. For one-direction
>   communication where the foreground application writes and the agent
>   only reads, we recommend using an isolated storage file with a Mutex.
>   We recommend that you do not use IsolatedStorageSettings to
>   communicate between processes because it is possible for the data to
>   become corrupt.

Easy way to do this:

[Easy way to save game in WP7 Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381836/easy-way-to-save-game-in-wp7-silverlight/14382853#14382853)