# WP8: Communication between Background Agent and App wire Storage File?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage, background-agent

I am trying to write a simple weather app as my first app.
I have to keep the numbers of http requests as low as possible and so I am using a isolatedStorageSetting within the app to save the requested data and the date and time of the last request. Before the app start a request it looks in this file to ask when was the last request and start a new request if 120 minutes are gone. 
All this works perfectly within the app but now I have to implement an Scheduled Task to update the live tile and lock screen in the background. But before the background agent request the data it has to look in this file to ask for the last update and rewrite the data after request. 
So what I need is a file that can be used for reading and writing by the app and the background agent. I now that I need a mutex and wo on... but my questions are

1. what is the right kind of file or database for this case? (isolatedStorgeSettings, isolatedStorgeFile or something else)
2. where I have to generate this file? (within the MainPage.xaml.cs or do I need a Class Lib. Project)
3. how is the syntax to read and write entries in this file from the app and the background agent?

Ok I have this example now just as test to understand the hole topic step by step...

1. I have a Class Library "DataLib" wich contains this:

   namespace DataLib
   {
   public class DataLib
   {

   ```
   public static string DatenHolen(string DatenPacket)
   {
       IsolatedStorageFile WetterDatenDatei = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

       try
       {
           //Create == Create OR Overwrite
           IsolatedStorageFileStream myStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("datei1.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Create, WetterDatenDatei);
           StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(myStream);
           writer.Write("Inhalt der Datei");
           writer.Close();
       }
       catch (Exception)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Fehler beim Schreiben der Datei");
       }

       try
       {
           IsolatedStorageFileStream myStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("datei1.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open, WetterDatenDatei);
           StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myStream);
           DatenPacket = reader.ReadToEnd();
           reader.Close();
       }

       catch (Exception)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Fehler beim Auslesen der Datei");
       }

       return DatenPacket;
   }
   ```

   }
   }
2. I have the app itself with MainPage.xaml.cs wich have a reference to DataLib and contains this:

   using DataLib;

...

```
txt_Test.Text = DataLib.DataLib.DatenHolen();
```

This line produce an error. I just wont to display the generated string within the textbox "txt_Test". Where is my misstake?

Comment: No overload for the data Get method takes 0 arguments.

Comment: remove parameter from this function declaration  `DatenHolen(string DatenPacket)` => `DatenHolen()` and put the `string DatenPacket = String.Empty;` after `IsolatedStorageFile WetterDatenDatei...`

Comment: Thanks - but but how does it looks if I have an async class and need to return more than one strings? somethin like this `public async static Task<List<String>> DatenHolen()`... `return string1, string2`

Comment: It's too much for one question. There is a lot answers and comments. Please, finish this question and open new. Regarding your question, it's better to create a class - container for settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use isolatedStorage, [but not the isolatedStorageSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202944%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Protect it with Mutex and there will be no problems.
2. Generate it where you need it.
3. Easiest way is [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

2: settings access:

```
public new static App Current
{
    get
    {
        return (App)Application.Current;
    }
}

static public MySettings mySettings = new MySettings();
```

Now you can access settting where you want by:

```
App.Current.mySettings.Save() // Load() ... etc.
```

Comment: thanks for 1. and 3. but I need this specific file everywhere I do not understand how I can get access to this file if it is not generated in current context.

Comment: You can save this file where you need. You'll save it to isolatedstorage and this file will be available for the app and background agent. The data, which you want to save can be placed into separate class (for example). This class can be placed into App.xaml.cs and with appropriate access properties it will be available at all pages of your app.

Comment: this "appropriate access properties" is exactly what I don't know how to do - but I have the direction now and will try it - thanks

Comment: For 2, if you are creating a utility class (MySettings) it should live in a class library. If you put the code in your application you won't be able to reference it from your background agent due to dependency restrictions.

Comment: I think I have to start from very beginning. I create a isoStorageFile `IsolatedStorageFile FileName = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();` now I have to write a sting in it... samething like that `FileName.Add("DataField", "ValueOfDataFieldAsString");` and then I have to read it within the Scheduler `string variable = FileName.DataField; if(variable == "ValueOfDataFieldAsString") {... action ...}` it would be a great help if you could give me the exact syntax of this.

Comment: [Take a look to this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381836/easy-way-to-save-game-in-wp7-silverlight/14382853#14382853)

Answer (score 2):

You can save settings in your app and have them accessible by your background agent by saving a file to IsolatedStorage. I use JSON.Net to save and read the file. I always save my settings in the .\Shared\ of my storage. This way I know I can always access it. I have created a class for storing and reading this information called [FileStorage](http://codepaste.net/63vh4o). Using this class you can save your settings quite easily. I will create a Save, and Load method in my settings so they can be read and updated with the current information.

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public bool SomeProp { get; set; }
    public double AnotherProp { get; set;}

    public void Save()
    {
        FileStorage.WriteSharedData("Settings.txt", this);
    }

    public static AppSettings Load()
    {
        return FileStorage.ReadSharedData<AppSettings>("Settings.txt");
    }
}
```

This class helps ensure that I can access the file and my settings without any issue.

I have had success when using IsolatedStorageSettings for my app and for my background agent. I only use IsolatedStorageSettings if memory is a concern as my other solution uses JSON.Net which consumes quite a bit of memory.

Comment: Hiden gems ;). Thanks for the useful classes. And I think the line in Load() should be .ReadSharedData<>

Comment: Fixed! Thanks for the heads up